# Syntax for subseting when using pandas (printing)

Tags: pandas, subset, seaborn

I am trying to address a certain column, but only the values that are within a subsetting rule for another column.

I tried:

```
Dataframe[Dataframe[ColumnA == 'Value'][Dataframe[Dataframe[ColumnB]]
```

Can someone point me into the direction of the correct syntax?

I would use that for printing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the data using a chained index as follows. The

```
Dataframe['ColumnA'] == 'Value'
```

piece is a boolean mask that's used. You could also use .loc, but I've tried to keep this as similar to your initial approach as possible.

```
Dataframe[Dataframe['ColumnA'] == 'Value']['ColumnB']
```

or

```
Dataframe['ColumnB'][Dataframe['ColumnA'] == 'Value']
```